# JSON Output encoding issue with accented characters and apostrophes

Tags: json, character-encoding

I have created a JS template with this code to output GeoJSON for our Google Maps;

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="places"
    }
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          {longitude},
          {latitude}
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "{title}",
        "url": "{url_title}",
        "address": "{addressline1}, {if addressline2}{addressline2}, {/if}{city}, {postalcode}",
        "icon": "/static/markers/place.png"
      }
    },{/exp:channel:entries}
  ]
}
```

However, some of the titles have an apostrophe or accented characters, which are being included in the GeoJSON like so;

```
Bar &#8216;67
CafÃ© and Bar
```

I was wondering if anyone knows how I can correct this?

Thanks

Comment: just for sure - is your JS file output with utf-8 in header? "Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=UTF-8"?

Comment: Hi Max, it doesn't appear to be. The template has been created with type JavaScript but in Developer Tools i'm seeing; `Content-Type:text/javascript` and no encoding.

Comment: so this is your answer - u need to add utf-8. If your server works with .htaccess - try to add line *AddDefaultCharset UTF-8*

Answer (score 1):

As we discus in comments, its most probable that you have this issue because server is not return correct charset (utf-8) by default. 
You can try next:

for apache - add into .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

for nginx:

```
charset utf-8;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Max. I tried this but it still doesn't appear to work. I also tried alternatives from http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setting-charset-in-htaccess.html.

Comment: Do you use https? .htaccess rules for remove index.php works for you?